# Periodical build and start another job at JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have the following scenario in JENKINS:

Job1 - Will run periodically every 10 minutes, but should stop the periodic construction when it gives "SUCCESS". Attention to this, he must build until he succeeds every 10 minutes, when he succeeds, he must activate the next job.

Job2 - Must be triggered by Job1 only once;

How to solve? Are there any plugins for this questioning?